# Background color for the last second row of the table

Tags: php, css, html-table, row

I want **red** color as the background for the last second row of the table.

But it is not changing.

I tried:

```
    $i = 0;
    $total = 0;
    $stmttr = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE BRN = :inv"); // Your query
    $stmttr->bindParam(':inv',$irn);
    $allRows = $stmttr->rowCount(); // Count Total rows available in result
    $tri = 0; // initiate variable to check <tr> status
        while($rowc)
        {
            extract($rowc);
            $i++;

?>

    <tr  <?php if(++$tri==$allRows) { ?> style="background-color: red;"<?php } ?>   >
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
```

See the full code:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $total = 0;
    $stmttr = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE BRN = :inv"); // Your query
    $stmttr->bindParam(':inv',$irn);
    $allRows = $stmttr->rowCount(); // Count Total rows available in result
    $tri = 0; // initiate variable to check <tr> status
        while($rowc)
        {
            extract($rowc);
            $i++;

?>

    <tr  <?php if(++$tri==$allRows) { ?> style="background-color: red;"<?php } ?>   >
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
        <?php echo $i; ?>
      </td>
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
        <?php
        $itm = $IRN;
        $stmti = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM item WHERE IRN = :iinv ');
        $stmti->bindParam(':iinv',$itm);
        $stmti->execute();
        $rowci = $stmti->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        echo $rowci['Name']; 
        $srv = $SRN;
        $stmts = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM service WHERE SRN = :sinv ');
        $stmts->bindParam(':sinv',$srv);
        $stmts->execute();
        $rowcs = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        ?>
        &nbsp;(<?php echo $rowcs['Name']; ?>)
      </td>
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
        <?php echo $Quantity; ?>
      </td>
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
        <?php echo $Amnt; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: things like "red color as the background for the last second row of the table" could be achieved using pure css ```:nth-last-child(2)``` check this http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/nth-last-child.htm

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin it is not necessary that table will always have 2 rows, rows are based on the database...

Comment: sorry I thought you mean "second row from the end".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is at: `$allRows = $stmttr->rowCount(); // Count Total rows available in result`

**It is not counting the rows available in MySQL**

The updated code:

```
$i = 0;
    $total = 0;
    $stmttr = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) As rows FROM invoice WHERE BRN = :inv"); // Your query
    $stmttr->bindParam(':inv',$irn);
    $stmttr->execute();
$cresult = $stmttr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$tf= ($cresult['rows']);
        while($rowc)
        {
            extract($rowc);
            $i++;

?>

    <tr  <?php if($i == $tf) { ?> style="background-color: red;"<?php } ?>   >
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">
```

Hope it helps you. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe you have a problem on your loop. What are on variable $rowc?
- Maybe you should add `<table>` before the first `<tr>` and `</table>` after
  the last `</tr>`?

And CSS should be in a css file, better practice!

I don't have your DB, but this code is working, if it's what you want.

```
<?php
$tri = 0;
$nbrows=10;

 ?>
<table>
<?php
while ($tri<$nbrows) {  ?>
    <tr <?php if(++$tri==$nbrows) { echo "style=\"background-color: red;\"";} ?> >
     <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">Your content </td>
      <td style="border-top:none !important; border-bottom:none !important;">Content 2 </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
 ?>
</table>
```